# Can a simple rand function be sent as OTP? What is the vulnerability in that?

Tags: security, password-protection, one-time-password

I am doing some research to decide on an approach to generate One Time Passwords. Based on the material I have encountered till now, everyone uses some hashing and cryptographic functions with random/pseudo random keys. Why cant a basic random function be used as a one time password? If the password generation only needs to happen in the server and is sent to the client(via text), are there any drawbacks in that approach?

Comment: What is "basic random function"?

Comment: Inbuilt random functions provided by the languages: Math.random() of Java for an example.

Comment: If you use random values, how do you get server and client to generate the same value?

Comment: I am looking to transmit the OTP via a second channel(text message) to the client. So it would only be the server which generates the value. (Let me reword the question to include that info)

Comment: If a random number generator is cryptographically strong - it's fine to use it, otherwise it's not. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html

Answer (score 4):

Non cryptographic PRNGs are not designed to be secure. Common weaknesses are:

- A too small seed. For example .net uses a 31 bit integer, which can be enumerated in a couple of seconds. The attacker observes a few outputs and eliminates the seeds which don't match the expectation. Once they're down to a single seed they can predict all future outputs.
- A predictable seed. e.g. the time. This either directly leads to the predictable outputs or at least narrows down the number of seeds to consider. For example if the time is in milliseconds and the attacker knows when the RNG was initialized to 20ms they have a 1/20 chance of guessing the seed and predicting the output.
- Given a enough outputs an attacker can recover the internal state of the PRNG and/or predict future outputs. This is the case for algorithms like the [Mersenne Twister](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister).

=> use a cryptographic PRNG instead. `/dev/urandom` on Linux and `CryptGenRandom` on Windows. If your language has built in wrappers for these, use them. In Java that's the `SecureRandom` class.

Answer (score 1):

I recently had an interesting discussion with security specialist on the use of random function. Depending on the library you use, the random is not so random, and would, in theory, give to someone a possibility to predict the result of the random and therefore guess the password. (For example the random function in VBA is not random. If you do not initialise the function, you get always the same random numbers in the same sequence)

Saying this, if you are not using a "real" random generating function, depending on the expected lifetime of you password (as it is a one time password I assume this is quite short), some kind of "randomisation" could be done, using for example the movements of the mouse on a given window, or some use of the "timer" of the machine before calling the random function to generate the password, if applicable...

Hope that helps